# Would replacing the parameter to a public method be considered refactoring, or is that going too far?

Tags: api, enums, refactoring

Let's say that I have a method with the signature:

```
public static bool ValidDateToSend(DateTime date, string frequency)
```

Inside of the method is a switch on frequency.

Would changing the frequency from a string to a public enum, be considered a refactor, or is that going too far?  Since this is a public method, there could potentially be many references outside of this code.  The strict definition of refactoring (and what I believe is meant by fearless refactoring) is

> disciplined technique for restructuring an existing body of code,
>   altering its internal structure without changing its external behavior

It seems to me that changing a method parameter to using a non-compatible type would indeed constitute "changing its external behavior".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "external behavior" is the behavior of the system itself in terms of inputs and outputs.  Modifying a signature is definitely a refactoring, although performing it safely may be difficult.  The only exception to this is when your product is an API, in which case modifying a signature would affect customers and would not be just a refactoring.

Comment: Though in this case there could be internal clients.  Lets assume that this is a change in a core helper functions class, and this method is used throughout the application, including in code that I don't necessarily have access to.  If this were private - I would agree with you, but since there could be other consumers of this method, it seems like it would make more sense to mark this as deprecated, and point it at a new method that uses the enum.  This method would just do the string to enum conversion.

Comment: If there are other developers involved you certainly should get their buy-in if it will break their code.  If frequency really is a constant in the client code then the refactoring will be fairly easy.  If frequency is not a constant then I would question whether you should refactor it into an enum.

Answer (score 0):

Changing its external behavior to me indicates that what the user of the code sees changes.  If the method itself is included in some kind of code library, this may be considered changing it's external behavior.  If the method is being used only internally and all references to the method change, the external behavior isn't changing, and so according to the definition you list, it is refactoring.  If it's in a code library, it could be considered an enhancement.  It may still be considered refactoring if you consider that users of the code library will have to refactor their code to use it and the end users of their code will see no difference.